# Update indexes when deleting nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the ability to highlight multiple nodes via mouseclick. I have a button that, when pressed, deleted all highlighted nodes. Now this works fine. Its just when I go to highlight them again.

The highlighting works by getting the index of the node that was just clicked. But after the deletion it seems the indexes haven't changed.

I have found this example : [D3 update on node removal always remove the last entry in SVG DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240842/d3-update-on-node-removal-always-remove-the-last-entry-in-svg-dom)

But it doesnt seem to solve my problem :(

Basically what I'm asking for is when I delete the nodes, how do I update the index's ?

Comment: Don't use the indices, use the data.

Comment: Thanks. It worked using the data. But the thing is, I wanted to use the index as sometimes I don't know if that piece of data will be available. Is there any way to give the nodes a unique value ? Even after deleting nodes and re-running the update function (which just sets the nodes and links)

Comment: You can generate an ID for each node. Can't really tell you any more without seeing what you're actually doing. In particular it's not clear to me what you mean when you say that a piece of data may not be available -- you still want to show something in this case?

Comment: its okay. Basically, I was giving a uinique number to each node when calling the update (); when i delete some nodes, I call the update again, thinking it will 'overwrite' the original unique number with a new one. But it just seemed to keep hold of the old one.

Comment: D3 doesn't do any magic behind the scenes -- if you want something to be updated, you have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Basically my problem was, when I was `splicing` the data, the array I was iterating over changes length, thus `i` wasn't at the correct location. So I decremented `i` in the loop when splicing the array. Something similar to this :

```
 for(i=0;i<nodeData.length;i++){
      if(nodeData[i].name === 'thisTest')
      {
        nodeData.splice(i--,1); 
      }
    }
```

This deletes `nodeData[i]` but at the same time decrements `i` so it is at the correct index in the array :)